# Net::HTTP.post form to rails application api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am fairly new to rails and ruby and would appreciate help with writing a ruby script to POST to a rails resource.  to make it simple, I created a simple rails application using the following code:

```
$ rails new apitest
$ cd apitest
$ bundle install
$ rails generate scaffold friends name:string age:float
$ rake db:migrate
$ rails server
```

I edited /app/controllers/friends.controller.rb and added to the FreindsController Class the following line:

```
protect_from_forgery :except => :create
```

The app is running fine, but I cannot get a ruby script to post a new record to the friends resource.  I tried the following ruby script:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'net/http'
require 'json/pure'
require 'uri'

uri = URI('http://localhost:3000/friends.json')

res = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, {"friend" => {"name" => "Joe", "age" => "80.2"}}) { 
    initheader = {'Content-Type' =>'application/json'}
    }
puts res
```

However, I get the following error:

```
#<Net::HTTPInternalServerError:0x007fe4891b4480>
```

Any help to get POST working would be fantastic!  an NET::HTTP.get works fine and returns a JSON with all the entries in the database.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you see in the Rails server logs when you run the POST-ing script?  It would also help to post the content of that create method...

Comment: {initheader = {}} is not a correct hash.
correct format:
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

HTTP.post_form URI('http://www.example.com/search.cgi'),
               { "q" => "ruby", "max" => "50" }

Comment: @Joeman29 Here is the create method:
`def create
    @friend = Friend.new(friend_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @friend.save
        format.html { redirect_to @friend, notice: 'Friend was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @friend }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @friend.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
`

Comment: @Joeman29 Here is the logs

`
Started POST "/friends.json" for ::1 at 2015-12-21 18:01:44 -0800
Processing by FriendsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"friend"=>"{\"name\"=>\"Joe\", \"age\"=>\"80.2\"}"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `permit' for "{\"name\"=>\"Joe\", \"age\"=>\"80.2\"}":String):
  app/controllers/friends_controller.rb:72:in `friend_params'
  app/controllers/friends_controller.rb:27:in `create'
`

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation for the post_form method](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.4/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-c-post_form):

**"The form data must be provided as a Hash mapping from String to String"**

So here your friend_params method, which I assume looks like this:

```
def freind_params
   params[:friend].permit ....
end
```

is problematic, since the friend param is being stringified.  If you want to use the post_form method, post the friend parameters in JSON format:

```
res = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, {"friend" => '{"name": "Joe", "age" : "80.2"}'}) { 
    initheader = {'Content-Type' =>'application/json'}
    }
```

And then in your Rails server create method change:

```
@friend = Friend.new(friend_params)
```

to

```
@friend = Friend.new(JSON.parse(friend_params))
```

and here is your new friend_params method:

```
def friend_params
  params.permit(:friend)
end
```

You could also use a gem like [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) if you don't want to deal with this, then you could just replace `Net::HTTP.post_form` with `HTTParty.post` and leave everything else as is.